# Type for a dynamic filling object Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I want to try dynamic typing on one of my projects.

I have an object that is initially empty but by the time it will get a structure like this:

```
{
 index: 2,
 0: {
    prop1: 4,
    prop2: 8,
    prop3: 15,
 },
 1: {
    prop1: 4,
    prop2: 8,
    prop3: 15,
 }
 // And so on
}
```

I tried different approaches but nothing worked well, the last thing I tried was this type:

```
{
    index: number;
    [key: string]: {
        prop1: number;
        prop2: number;
        prop3: number;
    }
};
```

It says that I can't use this type for my objects.

Comment: *"It says that I can't use this type for my objects."* Please always **directly quote** the error, and show the code that gave you that error, don't paraphrase it.

Comment: Separately: Why not an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define that interface largely as you said you tried to, though if the dynamic keys are always numbers, you can use `number`:

```typescript
interface TheThing {
    index: number;
    [key: number]: {
        prop1: number;
        prop2: number;
        prop3: number;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIdAc2QbwChkTlQATCADwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuY0gbQGsIAnnUatoAXTpFS05AAcoAe1kBGYczZROM0vKUAmNaM1dtu2QGZDGraQC+he4QA2EMMjh0MWdLmQBeAmIKajo9ABpiAAZJEzlFFToAFgjpMwNkAA4UnXjLZGUAVhTbFNVA1Piy5Ni0uiya3LpC4uIAelbkAEEQcmQAZwVkBRAHdiA)